# How can I access my Stack Exchange accounts if my OpenID provider shuts down?

Tags: support, openid, login

I couldn't log in with OpenID for a minute, and I went nuts. What will happen if my OpenID provider goes offline? Are there any recovery options?

Comment: Please include more details - right now, this is too vague to answer. For instance, which Open ID provider are you using? Stack Exchange's? Also, when you "went nuts", how far off your rocker did you land? Was this, "mumbling gibberish to yourself" nuts? Or "went on a shooting spree and now institutionalized" nuts? Or did you just snack on cashews until Open ID started working again?

Comment: When Facebook first introduced two-step verification logins (like there is in Gmail) I have immediately switched to it. Few days later Facebook stopped sending SMSes, thus I was unable to login to my Facebook account for 5 days! I use MyOpenID.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Enter your profile and click the "my logins", next to the "edit" link.  Choose "Add more logins..." and select one of the other billions of Open ID providers to create an account with.

Now you have a fallback login method.

Comment: a *potentially infinite* number of fallback methods, in fact..

Comment: Having a [StackExchange OpenID](https://openid.stackexchange.com/user) fallback, even if it's just for your SE account, is a good idea, because if that ever shuts down, chances are you won't need it anymore.